# Foreign Key already exists For Relation Error in EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, npgsql

I am using Entity Framework 6.4.x with Npgsql and code first approach.

I created the following entity:

```cs
    public class UserBankAccountTransaction
    {
        public long PayerBankAccountId { get; set; }
        
        [ForeignKey(nameof(PayerBankAccountId))]
        public virtual UserBankAccount PayerBankAccount { get; set; }
        
        public long PayeeBankAccountId { get; set; }
        
        [ForeignKey(nameof(PayeeBankAccountId))]
        public virtual UserBankAccount PayeeBankAccount { get; set; }
        
        [Required]
        public int Amount { get; set; }
    }
```

That is all, now when I do `Add-Migration` it creates a following migration:

```cs
    CreateTable(
                "public.UserBankAccountTransactions",
                c => new
                    {
                        Id = c.Long(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        PayerBankAccountId = c.Long(nullable: false),
                        PayeeBankAccountId = c.Long(nullable: false),
                        Amount = c.Int(nullable: false),
                        CreatedDate = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                        ModifiedDate = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
                .ForeignKey("public.UserBankAccounts", t => t.PayeeBankAccountId, cascadeDelete: true)
                .ForeignKey("public.UserBankAccounts", t => t.PayerBankAccountId, cascadeDelete: true)
                .Index(t => t.PayerBankAccountId)
                .Index(t => t.PayeeBankAccountId);
```

As you can see above in the automatically generated migration that `"public.UserBankAccounts"` is a foreign key being generated two times with same name.

Due to this When I `Update-Migration` I get this error:

```
constraint "FK_public.UserBankAccountTransactions_public.UserBankAccounts_P" for relation "UserBankAccountTransactions" already existsa
```

**Problem**

Isn't there a way to add more than one References/ForeignKeys to same table in EF6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres has limit for maximum length of identifier - [63 bytes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/limits.html), so both of your foreign keys end up with the same name - `FK_public.UserBankAccountTransactions_public.UserBankAccounts_P`.

So you need to find a way to specify FK name. Not sure that it can be done via attribute/fluent api (at least I was not able to find it) but as workaround you should be able to specify it via `name` parameter of [`TableBuilder<TColumns>.ForeignKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.migrations.builders.tablebuilder-1.foreignkey?view=entity-framework-6.2.0#System_Data_Entity_Migrations_Builders_TableBuilder_1_ForeignKey_System_String_System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func__0_System_Object___System_Boolean_System_String_System_Object_) method in the generated migration (which is usually not a good thing to do):

```
.ForeignKey("public.UserBankAccounts", t => t.PayeeBankAccountId, cascadeDelete: true, name: "FK_UBAT_UBA_PayeeBankAccountId" )
.ForeignKey("public.UserBankAccounts", t => t.PayerBankAccountId, cascadeDelete: true, name: "FK_UBAT_UBA_PayerBankAccountId")
```

Comment: That is for the UP, I can modify there, but what about Down? Not that I care about Down as I would normally never go "Down", I would normally go only "UP" in a migrations, just asking generally.

Comment: @user1735921 in this case "Down" should drop the table with all FK's so no need to change anything there.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue but with `Sql server` and I solved it like this:

```
public class UserBankAccountTransaction
    {
        [ForeignKey(nameof(PayerBankAccount))]
        public long PayerBankAccountId { get; set; }
        
        public virtual UserBankAccount PayerBankAccount { get; set; }
        
        [ForeignKey(nameof(PayeeBankAccount))]
        public long PayeeBankAccountId { get; set; }
        
        public virtual UserBankAccount PayeeBankAccount { get; set; }
        
        [Required]
        public int Amount { get; set; }
    }

public class UserBankAccount 
{
    //other properties

    [InverseProperty(nameof(UserBankAccountTransaction.PayerBankAccount))]
    public UserBankAccountTransaction PayerUserBankAccountTransaction { get; set; } 

    //or public List<UserBankAccountTransaction> PayerUserBankAccountTransactions { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty(nameof(UserBankAccountTransaction.PayeeBankAccount))]
    public UserBankAccountTransaction PayeeUserBankAccountTransaction { get; set; } // or list ...

}
```